# Tool to visualize system monitoring log on a web server

Tags: erlang, health-monitoring

I am sure there must be many existing ones there, just want to figure out what's the best fit for our requirements.

Basically we have a log file which we dump system monitoring data such as memory usage, CPU with timestamps.

What we want is to have a web server that visualize the system monitoring data live. I think it's not hard to implement (basically grab a window of data and draw some plots and put it on the web). Just wondering if there are existing tiny tools that are easy to use and have very friendly UIs.

I know Ambari provides interfaces that can visualize your data on live, while our system is very small and no need to bother that.

Many thanks,

ausgoo

Comment: so why is there `erlang` tag? if you need only cpu and memory usage info, there are plenty of out-of-the-box standalone solutions

Answer (score 0):

The best way I feel is to push the data to collectd and move the rrd to the graphite srever where you can view all the stats easily.